# can this use case be ever worked out in ehcache?

Tags: java, caching, asynchronous, synchronization, ehcache

i want to use ehcache not only as a cache but as a container of dirty objects that i want to flush to my database when the objects get evicted/expired. during normal processing, i use a key to lookup in ehcache. if key is not present, i read data from database and put it in ehcache. the value is actually a complex object that i modify. when the ttl/idle time/overflow condition happens, i see that CacheEventListener callbacks get invoked. but there is a big problem. the notifyElementExpired is called after the key-value are removed from cache. so there is a race condition. if i do the task of flushing the dirty value to cache in notifyElementExpired and at the same time, in another thread, read for the same key happens, then there is a synchronization issue. the 2nd thread will not find the object in ehcache, and hence will go to database while the other thread is still getting ready to flush.

i tried experimenting with write-through ehcache and i dont think thats also working.

is there a solution here??

i would really appreciate good solutions to this problem even if it involves some other caching mechanism other than ehcache.

thanks

Comment: I couldn't find any answer to this question myself. So I went ahead and solved it myself! Here is the solution that I blogged about -
http://blog.readypulse.com/2012/01/08/ehcache-as-a-true-persistent-store-backed-cache/

Comment: Nice work TVinodGupta. As a friendly reminder, can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer so that we can close this question? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok with a purely in-memory cache, I'd suggest extending the [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library's CacheLoader, ex:

```
public class DBLoader extends CacheLoader<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String load(String key) throws Exception {
        // load a value from the database
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then in usage, something like:

```
private LoadingCache<String, String> dbCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
.expireAfterWrite(CACHE_EXPIRE_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.build(new DBLoader());

String value = dbCache.get(someKey);
```

You'll need to tidy that up with proper exception handling of course.

I find guava to be much more straightforward than getting ehcache configured properly.